# How to safeguard json call for socketTimeout and httpTimeout

Tags: java, json

I have a java web module which does a number of json over http calls to another server. I've just been told by our java admin team that I need to safeguard against socketTimeouts and connection timeouts when making the json over http calls because when a response is not received in good time it is leaving hung threads on the server.

As a result I have been asked to set a timeout to 45 seconds.

Could I have some suggestions of the best way to set both a socket and http connection timeout on the code below...

```
  public static String readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws Exception{
      String jsonText = null;
      try {
          InputStream is = null;
          try {
              is = new URL(url).openStream();
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName(JsonConstants.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
              jsonText = readAll(rd);     
          } finally {
              if (is!=null){
                  is.close();  
              }               
          }
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new Exception(ErrorConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_MSG);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new Exception(ErrorConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_MSG);          
      }

      if (jsonText != null && jsonText.indexOf(JsonConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE) != -1){
          throw new Exception(ErrorConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_MSG);     
      }
      return jsonText;
  }
```

thanks in advance

---

### EDIT

I should have mentioned above that I'm using java 1.4.2 and setTimeout and setReadTimeout are not there on HttpUrlConnection in that version of java. I've been digging around but have not been able to find a nice snippet on how to do that yet. Appreciate it if someone could point me to a good example or add a good snippet of code that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `openStream()`. Use `openConnection()`, cast the result to `HttpURLConnection`, and then call the appropriate methods to set the required timeouts. Then call `getInputStream()` to get the data.

However the motivation is incorrect. If there is a connect timeout, there is no connection, so no thread at the server at all.

Comment: thanks for that. Just to expand on that. Would you mind telling me how the code below will lead a hung/open thread on the server if there is a connection timeout/socket timeout? Sorry I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Hi. What I failed to mention which I should have mentioned earlier was that I am using Java 1.4.2. It's a very old server. I've just found out that for 1.4.2 setTimeout and setReadTimeout on HttpUrlConnection are not there! Crap! I've done some research but can't find a good answer yet for java 1.4.2.

Comment: thanks for leading me in the right direction i've found a code snippet that i can use at http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1219068.